# Массив и указатель на него

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

По мере изучения массивов возникло 2 вопроса:

1.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int main (void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int a[5];
    cout << a << "\n" << &a << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Почему выводится один и тот же адрес?
Как читал, `а` - указатель на первый элемент массива. Мы выводим адрес этого первого элемента, а затем адрес указателя на него, но адрес один и тот же. Можете прояснить ситуацию?

2.
Запись

```
int a[5]
```

и

```
int (*a)[5]
```

Что означает второй пример, как с ним работать (с помощью new) и в чём его отличие от первого.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `a` - это не "указатель на первый элемент массива". `a` - это *сам массив*. Массив не является указателем.

   Однако в некоторых (весьма многочисленных) контекстах значение типа "массив" неявно автоматически *преобразуется* к значению типа "указатель на элемент массива". Этот указатель указывает на первый (нулевой) элемент массива. Отсюда и возникает иллюзия того, что массив является указателем.

   Но производится такое преобразование не всегда. Унарный встроенный оператор `&` - как раз пример *исключения*: операнд унарного `&` остается массивом. Поэтому в вашем случае `&a` - это не "адрес указателя", как вы неверно предположили, а адрес всего массива `a`. Он имеет тип `int (*)[5]`.

   В то же время проcто `a` в вашем примере подвергается такому преобразованию, т.е. дает указатель на первый элемент массива. Он имеет тип `int *`.

   Нет ничего удивительного в том, что численно эти адреса совпадают. Первый элемент массива начинается в памяти точно там же, где начинается и весь массив.
2. Второй пример - указатель на массив. Ничем принципиально от других указателей он не отличается и "работать" с ним следует так же, как и с любым другим типом указателя. Примените к этому указателю унарный оператор `*` - и вы получите доступ к указуемому массиву, который будет вести себя так же, как и любой другой массив.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Злит то, что не дают сразу полное, подробное описание темы (Что дают: "Вот, Лёша, есть такая вещь, массивом называется. У неё есть длина, а к элементам можно по индексу обращаться". Показывают синтаксис описания, обращения. Всё.), а то проходишь её, думаешь - всё, знаю, идешь дальше, а потом оказывается, что ты тему эту знал на половину. Ладно, если бы материал был очень сложным, чтобы не давать его сразу, так нет же...

Comment: Это не совсем так. Просто вы еще  не успели изучать подробно...  Для каждой темы есть учебники, где подробно   все  описывается

Comment: Не совсем понял "...не успели изучать..."."Есть"? Возможно. Где-то, может быть, и есть.